# Getting spam sent through website, but visitor not logged

Tags: analytics, spam, matomo

I'm getting spam messages send through my contact form on my website but the visitor is not logged at all in Piwik.

Does this mean that they disabled Java? Would they purposely go through that effort to avoid you logging their visit?

Comment: If there is such a vulnerability on your website, that disabling JavaScript would allow someone to send spam, you should mitigate that. This is in light of the information that most bots may not have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: @RanaPrathap The question is more focussed on the analytics, rather than the ability to send the spam.

Answer (score 1):

These are just bots abusing your email contact form, bots do that all the time and most of them have javascript (by java I think you meant javascript) disabled, it's one of the methods to identify bots, to check if they have javascript enabled or not. But of course it's not bulletproof either.

Instead you should analyze your server logs, if you want to learn more about these bots harvesting your site.